# Documentation for HSV color space in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, colors

The HSV-color space that OpenCV uses seems to be a model that forms a hexagonal pyramid according to [cvtColor](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtColor) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness).

The [article](http://alvyray.com/Papers/CG/color78.pdf) by Smith that is referenced on Wikipedia seems to agree as well with the transformation from RGB to HSV when it comes to S and V, but not for H.

Does anyone have a suggestion of a good source to cite for the model that is used in OpenCV? The source that OpenCV bases the color transformation on would be great if anyone knows.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I seem to have been unclear. I know how the OpenCV tranformation works. I was wondering if there exist another source (a book perhaps) that uses the same color transformation as that OpenCV uses. I guess that they based their transformation on some other source. But perhaps this is wrong and the only source is OpenCV.

Answer (score 3):

In this [link](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/HSV-ranges-td5156128.html) you have some explanation of HSV color model in OpenCV, I think it is quite useful.

And just in case you don't know yet, the online documentation of OpenCV also explains everything you need to know about classes and functions. Here you have a link to the [miscellaneous image transformations](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_miscellaneous_image_transformations.html?highlight=hsv). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found McConells book http://books.google.se/books?id=H5UVcCYSbXcC, which seems to describe almost the same HSV color model as OpenCV.